# Root of function with harmonic and exponential terms

Tags: trigonometry, roots

I'm trying to analytically obtain the root $t_r$ of the following expression:

$
f(t)=\text{$\mathcal{R}$1}\,\text{Sin}  (t\,\text{$\omega$})+\text{$\mathcal{R}$2}\,\text{Cos}  (t\, \text{$\omega$})+e^{-\text{$\zeta$}\, t\, \text{$\omega $}} \{\text{$\mathcal{R}$3}\,\text{Sin}  (t\, \text{$\omega_{D} $})+\text{$\mathcal{R}$4}\,\text{Cos}  (t\, \text{$\omega_{D}$})\}-\text{$a_{y}$};
$

where $\text{$\mathcal{R}$1}$, $\text{$\mathcal{R}$2}$, $\text{$\mathcal{R}$3}$, $\text{$\mathcal{R}$4}$ are constants, and $\omega_{D}=\omega\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}$.

such that $t_r$ is real and $t_r>0$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a question about mathematics, or instead *Mathematica*?

Comment: This is a question about mathematics. I had originally mentioned Mathematica so someone with an answer and knowledge of the software could take advantage of it within his/her reply.